# min over one dimension followed by max over another dimension

Tags: sql, table-statistics

I have an SQL table that looks like this:

```
i       j       x
0       0       0.5
0       1       1.0
0       2       1.5
1       0       1.4
1       1       1.3
1       2       1.2
```

and so on.  I would like to take the average over the `j` dimension followed by the minimum over the `i` dimension.  In this case, taking the average over the `j` dimension produces the following:

```
i       x
0       1.0
1       1.3
```

Taking the minimum over the `i` dimension then produces the value 1.0, which is the final result.  Is there an efficient way to perform a query like the one in this example, i.e., a query in which a sequence of dimension reduction operations is performed in a specified order?

Note that if we reverse the order of operations, the intermediate result is

```
j       x
0       0.5
1       1.0
2       1.2
```

Taking the average over the `j` dimension produces a final result of 0.9.  Thus, the order of operations is important.

Phillip

http://phillipmfeldman.org

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a subquery, of course:

```
SELECT MIN(avg_over_j) FROM (
   SELECT i, AVG(x) AS avg_over_j
   FROM TheTable 
   GROUP BY i
)
```

But this isn't APL or the J language; there's no "dimension reduction operations".